# Gostaria de saber o por que de o python estar dizendo que forneci 3 argumentos nessa função?

Tags: python-3.x

Código:

```
print("Jogo do chute...")

import random

numeroaleatorio = random.randrange(100)
chutes = 0
r = True

while r:
    chute = int(input("Digite um número de zero(0) a cem(100): "))
    if chute > numeroaleatorio:
        print("Número muito alto...")
        chutes +=1

    elif chute < numeroaleatorio:
        print("Número muito baixo...")
        chutes +=1

    elif chute == numeroaleatorio:
        print("Você acertou...\nA quantidade de chutes que você deu foram %i"%chutes)
        break
```

Menssagem de erro:

```
Jogo do chute...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "y.py", line 41, in <module>
    numeroaleatorio = random.choice(1, 100)
TypeError: choice() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Visto isso por que o python está dizendo que forneci 3 argumentos sendo que apenas forneci dois argumentos '1' e '100' ?

Comment: No erro ele apresenta o código: `numeroaleatorio = random.choice(1, 100)` e no exemplo está com o código `numeroaleatorio = random.randrange(100)`. Por que?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em python 3 voce deveria gerar o valor randomico que voce deseja dessa maneira:

### randrange:

```
from random import randrange
rnd = randrange(1,100)
```

**Output:**

```
print(rnd)
92
```

Ou ainda:

### choice:

```
from random import choice
rnd = choice(range(1,100))
```

**Output:**

```
print (rnd)  
61
```

[Execute o código no repl.it](https://repl.it/JPD2/0)

Answer (score 1):

O intuito é escolher um número de 1 a 100?

Podes usar

```
random.randrange(1, 100);

//random.randrange([start], stop[, step])
```

ou

```
random.choice(range(1, 100, 1))

//random.choice(range(start, stop, step))
```